# Reputation on the recent page but it does not change next to the name on the top bar.

Tags: support, reputation

I noticed reputation changes on the recent page but it does not change next to the name on the top bar. Is this planned or a bug?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: You mean for you the rep on meta changes on the top bar?

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant the main site. No, I don't see any rep change on meta.

Comment: Ah, well. Bug? =)

Comment: Well it just showed up for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you are referring to here.

If you mean your reputation on meta, that is synced hourly between parent and child meta. Votes here on meta do NOT affect reputation in any way.

If you mean your reputation on the parent site, I'm not aware of any bugs that would prevent reputation from working as normal.

Comment: Thanks. I got my answer. I was referring to the meta-site.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a delay to rep being applied between the main site and the Meta site.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this with Safari 5 on Snow Leopard 10.6.4 and I suspect this is because of the new cache system of Safari (or maybe of Mac OS X ?) and not a bug of this site precisely as it also appeared on StackOverflow, ServerFault, …

Comment: happens to me in FireFox as well.